# automatic solution for cut-off captions?

Tags: floats, captions

Captions for my figures are getting cut off in a relatively benign setting.  I do not want to resize my figures.  There may be unsavory things about the formatting of the images themselves, but that does not negate the fact that I want them to span the whole page; so making adjustments to the ugly Matlab plots is also not a solution.  I also don't want to waste lots of time trying out different positions for the figures-- this is TeX, after all, so it seems there should be some kind of automatic solution.  In the MWE, the missing caption is Abbildung 1.1, as one can (not) see in the screenshot.[image: Red oval encompasses where "Abbildung 1.1" should be.]

```
\documentclass[final]{siamltex}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\title{MWE for cut-off captions}
\author{Der herrlichste Herr}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\Blindtext

\section{Polynomial studies}

    \newcommand{\imsize}{\textwidth}
    \subsection{Case 1}
    \textbf{Abbildung~\ref{fig:case1} ist großartig!}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width = \imsize]{case1}
        \end{center}
        \caption{\label{fig:case1}}
    \end{figure}    

    \subsection{Case 2}
    \textbf{Abbildung~\ref{fig:case2} ist super geil!}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width = \imsize]{case2}
        \end{center}
        \caption{\label{fig:case2}}
    \end{figure}


    \subsection{Case 3}
    \textbf{Abbildung~\ref{fig:case3} ist die beste!}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width = \imsize]{case3}
        \end{center}
        \caption{\label{fig:case3}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To generate exactly the same document as I have, here are the images I'm using:[image: case 1] [image: case 2] [image: case 3]  Enjoy.

Comment: We cannot do much without having that class file...

Comment: http://etna.math.kent.edu/LaTeX/siamltex.cls

Comment: The compiler longs for the `.clo` files…

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siam?lang=en .  If that is too difficult, then just substitute \documentclass[final]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} for \documentclass[final]{siamltex}.  The problem still occurs.